# Why am I getting this segmentation fault on solaris?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, solaris, uuid

So to start off this code works on all my redhat machines and some other solaris machines.  The machine that is producing the fault is a solaris 64 bit.  The code I have is as follows:

This is the frUUID class:

```
  frUUID::frUUID()
  {}

  std::string frUUID::genUUID()
  {
    char uuidBuff[36];
    uuid_t uuidGenerated;
    uuid_generate_random(uuidGenerated);
    uuid_unparse(uuidGenerated, uuidBuff);

    std::cout << uuidBuff << std::endl; // prints out a correct uuid

    return std::string(uuidBuff);
  }
```

Then in a unit test I have:

```
 frUUID uuids;

 std::string uuid1 = uuids.genUUID();
 std::cout << std::endl << "UUID 1: " << uuid1 << std::endl; 
 //This cout produces the seg fault on the uuid1
```

I have no idea what is going on here everything seems to be correct?  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not leaving space for the trailing null byte in `uuidBuff`.

Answer (score 4):

From the [`uuid_unparse`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/3/uuid_unparse/) man page:

> The uuid_unparse function converts the supplied UUID uu from the internal binary format into a 36-byte string (**plus tailing '\0'**)

Your buffer is too small for that. You're in undefined behavior territory.

Comment: Thank you my heads been spinning around this for hours, I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

change

char uuidBuff[36];

to

char uuidBuff[37];

for the null character